# Calculating bipartite state from joint probability distribution

Tags: measurement, state-tomography

We can calculate single qubit state by measuring it in pauli observables {$\sigma_{x},\sigma_{y},\sigma_{z}$} and then looking at its probability distribution. How to do this when we are having joint probability distribution for multiqubit state? Specifically, I want to know the procedure for calculating 2-qubit state when it's measured in $\sigma_{x}\otimes\sigma_{x}$, $\sigma_{y}\otimes\sigma_{y}$ and $\sigma_{z}\otimes\sigma_{z}$ observables?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This would not be enough information to reconstruct the bi-partite state.

### Single-qubit case

For the one-qubit case, reconstruction of the state (which we describe as $\rho$) works, because the single-qubit Pauli observables $\{\sigma_{x},\sigma_{y},\sigma_{z}\}$ together with the $\sigma_{I}$-operator creates a basis for the space of single-qubit density matrices. If our probabilities are $\{p_{I}=1,p_{x},p_{y}.p_{z}\}$, we reconstruct as:
$$
\rho = \sum_{i \in \{I,x,y,z\}} p_{i}\sigma_{i}.
$$

### Bi-partite case

In principle we can do this also for a bi-partite state, but the operators over which we sum still need to form a basis for the space of (now bi-partite) density matrices. A simple count of the dimensions involved tells us that there should be $16$ elements in this basis, and not the four in $\{I, \sigma_{x}\otimes \sigma_{x},\sigma_{y}\otimes \sigma_{y},\sigma_{z}\otimes \sigma_{z}\}$.

The most obvious (and used) choice is to also include the cross products of all the Paulis. We then get a set of $4^{2} = 16$ elements, which is called the two-qubit Pauli group $\mathcal{P}^{2}$:

$$
\mathcal{P}^{2} = \{\sigma_{I},\sigma_{x},\sigma_{y},\sigma_{z}\} \otimes \{\sigma_{I},\sigma_{x},\sigma_{y},\sigma_{z}\}.
$$
If we would have all $16$ $p_{i}$'s, the reconstruction is as straightforward for the one-qubit case:
$$
\rho_{2} = \sum_{i \in \{I,x,y,z\}\times \{I,x,y,z\}} p_{i}\sigma_{i}.
$$

You said you already have $p_{x,x}, p_{y,y}$ and $p_{z,z}$. $p_{I,I}$ is a freebie because it needs to be $1$; so you still need the $12$ other probabilities.

### Some intuition

Basically, the above analysis tells us that to completely characterize our system of two qubits, knowing only what they do in this symmetric-coupling sense is not enough information. Basically, we are missing two sets of information:

- We need to know how these two qubits act under *aymmetric* coupling. That is to say, we need the probabilities for measurements of e.g. $\sigma_{x} \otimes \sigma_{y}$, or $\sigma_{z} \otimes \sigma_{x}$. Of course, there are $|\{x,y,z\}\times \{x,y,z\}|=9$ different elements here, but we already counted the three symmetric ones.
- We also need to know what they do *individually*: if we measure 'nothing' on the first qubit but we measure the second qubit in any of the Pauli bases, we still learn something about the second qubit. These are the operators $\sigma_{I}\otimes \{\sigma_{x},\sigma_{y},\sigma_{z}\}$ and vice-versa: there are $6$ of them.

This gives a total of $1$ (for $\sigma_{I}\otimes \sigma_{I}$) + $3$ (for our original $3$ operators) + $9-3 = 6$ (for the asymmetric coupling operators) + $6$ (for the individual operators). This sums up to $16$, so we now have accounted for all of the operators.

### Then how to actually get these other probabilities?

[This question](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/9014/quantum-tomography-on-two-qubits) deals with the same problem, and there I also [explain](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/9026/8141) how to obtain these $12$ other probabilities from experimental outcomes. Note that these $3$ measurements really *are* not enough, and that you will need at least $9$ different measurement results: you need all symmetric and asymmetric operators.

### Final note + further reading

As a last remark, the techniques of reconstructing density matrices from probability distributions (or a finite number of measurement outcomes) are collectively known as *quantum state tomography* or QST (It even has a [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_tomography), hurray!). There are many more advanced techniques, but I won't go into them here - if you ever want to learn more googling the term QST is a good start, but of course you should also feel free to ask any questions on the stack exchange.

Answer (score 0):

**1. Calculating $\langle \sigma_z \otimes \sigma_z \rangle$**

$$\langle \sigma_z \otimes \sigma_z \rangle = Tr\big(\sigma_z \otimes \sigma_z \rho\big) = \rho_{11} - \rho_{22} - \rho_{33} + \rho_{44}$$

As can be seen from this [answer](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/9026/9459) $\rho_{11}$, $\rho_{22}$, $\rho_{33}$ and $\rho_{44}$ are the probabilities of measuring $|00\rangle$, $|01\rangle$, $|10\rangle$ and $|11\rangle$ correspondingly. This can be seen for example by calculating $Tr(P_{01} \rho) = \rho_{22}$, where $P_{01} = |01\rangle \langle 01|$ is the projector for the $|01\rangle$. Note, that $\rho_{11}$, $\rho_{22}$, $\rho_{33}$ and $\rho_{44}$ can be calculated from repeated experiments by applying $\sigma_z$ basis measurements (also it is described in this [answer](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/9026/9459)).

**2. Calculating $\langle \sigma_x \otimes \sigma_x \rangle$**

$$\langle \sigma_x \otimes \sigma_x \rangle = Tr\big(\sigma_x \otimes \sigma_x \rho\big) = Tr\big((H \otimes H) \; \sigma_z \otimes \sigma_z \; (H \otimes H) \; \rho\big) =
\\
= Tr\big( \sigma_z \otimes \sigma_z \; (H \otimes H) \; \rho \; (H \otimes H) \big) = Tr\big( \sigma_z \otimes \sigma_z \; \rho'\big) = \rho'_{11} - \rho'_{22} - \rho'_{33} + \rho'_{44}$$

Because $H\sigma_z H = \sigma_x$ and the [cyclic property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_(linear_algebra)#:%7E:text=the%20inner%20product%3A-,Cyclic%20property,known%20as%20the%20cyclic%20property.&text=where%20the%20first%20equality%20is,is%20not%20true%20in%20general.) of the trace. Here $\rho' =  H \otimes H \; \rho \; H \otimes H$. So, after applying $H\otimes H$ the the initial $\rho$ we just need to calculate $Tr\big( \sigma_z \otimes \sigma_z \; \rho'\big)$  that we already know how to do.

**3. Calculating $\langle \sigma_y \otimes \sigma_y \rangle$**

The same works, but instead of $H$, we take $H S^{\dagger}$:

$$
\langle \sigma_y \otimes \sigma_y \rangle = Tr\big( \sigma_z \otimes \sigma_z \; \rho''\big) = \rho''_{11} - \rho''_{22} - \rho''_{33} + \rho''_{44}
$$

where $\rho'' = \big(HS^{\dagger} \otimes HS^{\dagger} \big) \; \rho \; \big(SH \otimes SH \big)$, because $SH\sigma_z HS^\dagger = \sigma_y$ as can be seen from this [answer](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/11789/9459).

---

In a slightly different way, the same logic works for the other Pauli terms (we just need to apply such gates, after which we will have either $\sigma_z$ or $I$ in the trace). But of course, if we can measure also in $\sigma_x$ and $\sigma_y$ basis directly the gates before the measurements will be unnecessary. As was pointed out in this [answer](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/13116/9459) we should calculate all $16$ Pauli terms in order to estimate the density matrix (the mentioned three are not enough).

---

It is possible to combine measurements for $\langle \sigma_y \otimes \sigma_y \rangle$ and $\langle \sigma_x \otimes \sigma_x \rangle$, by measuring in Bell basis as was discussed in this [question](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/9192/9459).

Comment: I think the question was how to perform this the other way around - rather than calculating the expectation values for these operators, I interpreted the question as 'if I have these probabilities/expectation values, how do I calculate/reconstruct $\rho$'?

Comment: @JSdJ probably you are right.

Comment: Thank you @DavitKhachatryan

Comment: @Omkar you are welcome. I think I misunderstood the question and this is not a relevant answer. Somebody even downvoted the answer...So I guess I should delete this post.

Comment: I found it helpful @DavitKhachatryan. So i don't think you should delete this answer.

Comment: @Omkar, ok, then I will keep the answer :)