# Measuring Pauli strings using generators

Tags: mathematics, measurement, vqe

I am trying to find the ground state of a Hamiltonian using VQE. I have decomposed the Hamiltonian into a set of Pauli strings. To decrease the number of actual measurements that has to be done, can I just measure the generators of this set of Pauli strings? For example, say if the set is $\{I, Z_1Z_2, Z_2Z_3, Z_1Z_3\}$, can I just measure $Z_1Z_2$, and $Z_2Z_3$, and then find the expectation value of $Z_1Z_3$ from the expectation values of $Z_1Z_2$ and $Z_2Z_3$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here I am going to show why $\langle Z_1 Z_3 \rangle$ generally cannot be estimated from $\langle Z_1 Z_2 \rangle$ and $\langle Z_2 Z_3 \rangle$. Let's start with an arbitrary three-qubit state:

\begin{align*}
|\psi \rangle = c_{000} &|000\rangle + c_{001} |001\rangle + c_{010} |010\rangle + c_{011} |011\rangle + 
\\
+c_{100} &|100\rangle + c_{101} |101\rangle + c_{110} |110\rangle + c_{111} |111\rangle
\end{align*}

And because of this [answer](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/13675/9459) the expectation value for $Z_1 Z_2$, $Z_2 Z_3$ and $Z_1 Z_3$ (I am using this convention for qubit indexes $|q_1 q_2 q_3 \rangle$):

$$
\langle Z_1 Z_2 \rangle = |c_{000}|^2 + |c_{001}|^2 - |c_{010}|^2 - |c_{011}|^2 - |c_{100}|^2 - |c_{101}|^2 + |c_{110}|^2 + |c_{111}|^2
\\
\langle Z_2 Z_3 \rangle = |c_{000}|^2 - |c_{001}|^2 - |c_{010}|^2 + |c_{011}|^2 + |c_{100}|^2 - |c_{101}|^2 - |c_{110}|^2 + |c_{111}|^2
\\
\langle Z_1 Z_3 \rangle = |c_{000}|^2 - |c_{001}|^2 + |c_{010}|^2 - |c_{011}|^2 - |c_{100}|^2 + |c_{101}|^2 - |c_{110}|^2 + |c_{111}|^2
$$

From this expressions one can see that $\langle Z_1 Z_3 \rangle$ generally cannot be estimated from $\langle Z_1 Z_2 \rangle$ and $\langle Z_1 Z_3 \rangle$. For prove let's consider this conterexample when $|c_{000}| = |c_{010}|$, $|c_{001}| = |c_{011}|$:

\begin{equation*}
\langle Z_1 Z_2 \rangle = - |c_{100}|^2 - |c_{101}|^2 + |c_{110}|^2 + |c_{111}|^2
\\
\langle Z_2 Z_3 \rangle = |c_{100}|^2 - |c_{101}|^2 - |c_{110}|^2 + |c_{111}|^2
\\
\langle Z_1 Z_3 \rangle = 2|c_{000}|^2 - 2|c_{001}|^2 - |c_{100}|^2 + |c_{101}|^2 - |c_{110}|^2 + |c_{111}|^2
\end{equation*}

So for the same $\langle Z_1 Z_2 \rangle$ and $\langle Z_2 Z_3 \rangle$ there can be many different possible values for $\langle Z_1 Z_3\rangle$ because by varying the values $|c_{000}| = |c_{010}|$ and $|c_{001}| = |c_{011}|$ the expectations $\langle Z_1 Z_2 \rangle$ and $\langle Z_2 Z_3 \rangle$ will not be changed but  $\langle Z_1 Z_3 \rangle$ will be changed. So $\langle Z_1 Z_3 \rangle$ cannot be estimated from $\langle Z_1 Z_2 \rangle$ and $\langle Z_2 Z_3 \rangle$ in this conterexample.

Comment: This makes sense. But if I were to just make a measurement, instead of finding the expectation value, then could I have done so? For example, in this paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1907.13623, they mention that they can measure $Y_1Y_2$ by measuring $X_1X_2$ and $Z_1Z_2$.

Comment: I think I understand it now. If we can do a qubit-wise multiplication then we can obtain the expectation value, i.e. qubit-wise multiplication of $XX$ and $ZZ$ is proportional to $YY$, but qubit-wise multiplication of $Z_1Z_2$ and $Z_2Z_3$ is not $Z_1Z_3$.

Comment: @e-eight, in paragraph 7.2 they show how one can group $XX$, $YY$, and $ZZ$ in order to measure their expectation values together if I understood right. That can be done because they have simultaneous (common) eigenvectors...this can happen if operators commute with each other. This [answer](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/10173/9459) might be interesting in this regard where a simpler example is discussed. This [answer](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/13924/9459) also is about grouping Pauli strings.

Comment: @e-eight, I might be wrong about $\langle YY \rangle =? -\langle XX \rangle \langle ZZ \rangle$...maybe this is not what the paper implies. I need to think about this.

Comment: @e-eight, that is not what they meant and I was wrong... I am deleting my wrong comment because $\langle YY \rangle \ne -\langle XX \rangle \langle ZZ \rangle$. But $YY = -(XX)(ZZ)$ is correct.

Comment: @e-eight, why the expectation values of $XX$, $YY$, and $ZZ$ can be computed simultaneously with a single circuit? Because they have a common eigenbasis (Bell states) in which we can apply measurement (simultaneously we can call this $XX$ basis measurement or $YY$ basis measurement or $ZZ$ basis measurement). In the same way, the expectation values of $ZZ$, $ZI$, and $IZ$ can be measured simultaneously because they have a common eigenbasis (computational basis).

Comment: @e-eight, I am not sure if I understand what you mean by saying qubit-wise multiplication, because $Z_1 Z_2 I_3 \cdot I_1 Z_2 Z_3 = Z_1 I_2 Z_3$, but want to emphasize that the crucial point is to find a common eigenbasis for operators that one wants to group in a single measurement circuit...if there are no common eigenbasis for those operators one cannot do simultaneous measurement with one circuit.

Comment: @e-eight, if by measurement they mean finding if the state is in $+1$ or $-1$ eigenspace of the Pauli string operator, then note that for Bell state $|\Phi^-\rangle$ that is in $+1$ eigenspace of $YY$  we have $YY |\Phi^- \rangle = -(XX) (ZZ) |\Phi^- \rangle = -(-1) (+1) |\Phi^- \rangle =  (+1)|\Phi^- \rangle$, because $|\Phi^- \rangle$ is in the $+1$ eigenspace for $ZZ$ operator and $-1$ eigenspace for $XX$ operator. So, after Bell basis measurement if we know in what eigenspace is our measured state for $XX$ and $ZZ$ we will be able to find what is the corresponding eigenspace for $YY$.

Comment: My bad, yes $Z_1Z_2I_3 \cdot I_1Z_2Z_3 = Z_1I_2Z_3$. Now that I think about it, it makes sense that this will be possible only if they are commuting, i.e. they have a common eigenbasis.

Comment: @e-eight, and note that $Z_1 Z_2$ and $Z_2 Z_3$ and $Z_1 Z_3$ have common eigenbasis and can be measured with a single circuit, and it is not a contradiction with the answer that answers to a different question than this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115664/discussion-between-e-eight-and-davit-khachatryan).