# Quantum circuit to get expectation values of Pauli matrices, given state $|\psi\rangle$

Tags: circuit-construction, hhl-algorithm

I'm trying to solve 2 linear equations with the help of HHL algorithm. I've taken $A=\begin{pmatrix}
1.5 & 0.5\\
0.5 & 1.5\\
\end{pmatrix}$ and $b=\begin{pmatrix}
1\\
0\\
\end{pmatrix}$. I've implemented the circuit [here](https://algassert.com/quirk#circuit=%7B%22cols%22:[[1,%22H%22,%22H%22],[1,1,%22~rh1n%22],[1,1,%22%E2%80%A2%22,%7B%22id%22:%22Rxft%22,%22arg%22:%22-pi/2%22%7D],[],[1,%22~35nf%22],[1,%22%E2%80%A2%22,1,%7B%22id%22:%22Rxft%22,%22arg%22:%22-pi%22%7D],[1,%22Swap%22,%22Swap%22],[1,1,%22H%22],[1,%22~js47%22,%22%E2%80%A2%22],[1,%22H%22],[%7B%22id%22:%22Ryft%22,%22arg%22:%22pi%20%22%7D,1,%22%E2%80%A2%22],[%7B%22id%22:%22Ryft%22,%22arg%22:%22pi/3%22%7D,%22%E2%80%A2%22],[1,%22H%22],[1,%22~3ig4%22,%22%E2%80%A2%22],[1,1,%22H%22],[1,%22Swap%22,%22Swap%22],[1,%22%E2%80%A2%22,1,%7B%22id%22:%22Rxft%22,%22arg%22:%22pi%20%22%7D],[1,%22~utui%22],[1,1,%22%E2%80%A2%22,%7B%22id%22:%22Rxft%22,%22arg%22:%22pi/2%22%7D],[1,1,%22~o3fm%22],[1,%22H%22,%22H%22],[%22|1%E2%9F%A9%E2%9F%A81|%22]],%22gates%22:[%7B%22id%22:%22~rh1n%22,%22name%22:%22U1(3pi/4)%22,%22matrix%22:%22%7B%7B1,0%7D,%7B0,-%E2%88%9A%C2%BD+%E2%88%9A%C2%BDi%7D%7D%22%7D,%7B%22id%22:%22~o3fm%22,%22name%22:%22U1(-3pi/4)%22,%22matrix%22:%22%7B%7B1,0%7D,%7B0,-%E2%88%9A%C2%BD-%E2%88%9A%C2%BDi%7D%7D%22%7D,%7B%22id%22:%22~35nf%22,%22name%22:%22U1(3pi/2)%22,%22matrix%22:%22%7B%7B1,0%7D,%7B0,-i%7D%7D%22%7D,%7B%22id%22:%22~utui%22,%22name%22:%22U1(-3pi/2)%22,%22matrix%22:%22%7B%7B1,0%7D,%7B0,i%7D%7D%22%7D,%7B%22id%22:%22~3ig4%22,%22name%22:%22R2%22,%22matrix%22:%22%7B%7B1,0%7D,%7B0,i%7D%7D%22%7D,%7B%22id%22:%22~js47%22,%22name%22:%22R2%5Et%22,%22matrix%22:%22%7B%7B1,0%7D,%7B0,-i%7D%7D%22%7D]%7D), on quirk.

**Question**

How do I get expectation value of Pauli matrices in the above circuit?

Comment: Why do you  want to find the expectation values of Pauli matrices in the HHL algorithm? Is that because you want to do a tomography of the state? Here is the link of my tutorial for the VQE algorithm where procedures for finding expectation values for X, Y, and Z Pauli matrices are described https://github.com/DavitKhach/quantum-algorithms-tutorials/blob/master/variational_quantum_eigensolver.ipynb.

Comment: Here https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/9014/quantum-tomography-on-two-qubits you can find something on quantum tomography.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To find the expectation value of a given Pauli matrix, you just measure in the basis defined by the Pauli matrix. For example, to evaluate the expectation value of the $X$ matrix, you find the basis vectors of the $X$ matrix. These are $|+\rangle$ and $|-\rangle$, with corresponding eigenvalues +1 and -1. You measure in the $|\pm\rangle$ basis many times and find the probability of getting either result, $p_\pm$. Then, finally, the expectation value is $p_+-p_-$ (the numbers multiplying the $p_{\pm}$ terms correspond to the eigenvalues).